# What is the difference between #+TBLNAME and #+NAME in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

What is the difference between giving a table a name using `#+TBLNAME` and `#+NAME` in org-mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Org mode 8.2.10 is very old. If you can, you should upgrade. `TBLNAME` is deprecated (since version 8.3.4) : you should not use it any longer. It is still (in version 9.3) recognized for backward compatibility but it is likely to go away at some point. As for the link behavior mentioned in your answer, in recent versions of Org mode, `[[a and b]]` still results in the `No match` question, but `[[c and d]]` is a fully functioning link to the corresponding table.

Answer (score 0):

Given two tables below only the one named using `NAME` can be
referenced in prose with a navigable link.

```
#+TBLNAME: a and b
| a | b |
| 1 | 2 |

#+NAME: c and d
| c | d |
| 1 | 2 |
```

The link `[[c and d]]` will not be navigable with `C-c C-o` while attempting
the same with the link `[[a and b]]` will result in the user being asked:

> No match - create this as a new heading? (y or n)

But this is only part of the answer, there surely are more differences
than this.

This is with org-mode 8.2.10 released with Emacs 25.2.2.